# Finding a function from a name within a string

Tags: performance, c

The code is designed to see if the first alphabetic characters in the `*str` argument refers to a known function, as part of a calculator app, and sets `*str` to the first character after the name of the mathematical function if found, similar to the `endptr` argument in `strtol`, `strtod`, etc. I seek to make this code as direct as possible, eliminating redundant/unnecessary steps.

```
static int c(const void *const restrict a, const void *const restrict b) {
    const char *const sa = *(const char *const *)a, *const sb = *(const char *const *)b;
    const size_t l = strlen(sb);
    const int cmp = memcmp(sa, sb, l);
    return cmp ? cmp : isalpha(sa[l]) ? sa[l]-sb[l] : 0;
}
static double (*func(const char **const str))(double) {
    static const char *const s[] = {"abs", "acos", "acosh", "asin", "asinh", "atan", "atanh", "cbrt", "ceil", "cos", "cosh", "erf", "erfc", "floor", "gamma", "ln", "log", "round", "sin", "sinh", "sqrt", "tan", "tanh", "trunc"};
    static double (*const f[])(double) = {fabs, acos, acosh, asin, asinh, atan, atanh, cbrt, ceil, cos, cosh, erf, erfc, floor, tgamma, log, log10, round, sin, sinh, sqrt, tan, tanh, trunc};
    const char *const *const r = bsearch(str, s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s), sizeof(*s), c);
    return r ? *str += strlen(r), f[r-s] : NULL;
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
const char *s = "log100";
printf("%g\n", func(&s)(strtod(s, NULL))); // Prints 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Missing includes

We need a definition for `size_t` and the mathematical functions for this to compile; we also use undefined functions whose return type is not `int`.  I recommend including prototypes for all of them:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Even then, `abs`, `gamma` and `ln` are not defined.  I'm guessing `fabs`, `tgamma` and `log` were intended (and `log10` where `log` is used).

`restrict` is unnecessary in the comparison function `c()`, since no values are modified.

`memcmp(sa, sb, l)` is undefined behaviour unless we already know that string `sa` is longer than `sb`, as is the subsequent dereference `sa[l]`.  On the other hand, `sb[l]` is known to be zero.

Don't forget that we should be casting to `unsigned char` before passing characters to `<ctype.h>` functions.  And if we ever want to use function names such as `log2`, we'll want to use `isalnum()` rather than `isalpha()`.

I'm not a fan of the side-by-side arrays that must agree; that's a maintenance nightmare.  Prefer an array of pairs to a pair of arrays.  And we *definitely* need a comment telling future maintainers that the elements are required to be in sorted order.

`strlen(r)` doesn't make sense given that `r` is a `char**` - was `strlen(*r)` intended?  I'm surprised that it passes basic unit tests.

---

## Modified code

I've addressed all the issues I identified above.  The testing is minimal, and should be greatly expanded, probably using one of the available test frameworks.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct math_fun {
    const char* name;
    double (*func)(double);
};

static int compare_function_name(const void *a,
                                 const void *b)
{
    const char *const *const key = a;
    const struct math_fun *const entry = b;

    const size_t entry_len = strlen(entry->name);
    const int cmp = strncmp(*key, entry->name, entry_len);
    if (cmp) {
        /* mismatch: return as is */
        return cmp;
    }
    /* else b is a prefix of a - match only a complete word, else a > b */
    return isalpha((unsigned char)(*key)[entry_len]);
}

/* If the first word of `str` matches a function name, returns the
   corresponding function and advances `str` to the next character,
   else returns a null function-pointer. */
static double (*func(const char **const str))(double)
{
    static const struct math_fun functions[] = {
        /* N.B. must be in `strcmp()` order */
        { "abs", fabs },
        { "acos", acos },
        { "acosh", acosh },
        { "asin", asin },
        { "asinh", asinh },
        { "atan", atan },
        { "atanh", atanh },
        { "cbrt", cbrt },
        { "ceil", ceil },
        { "cos", cos },
        { "cosh", cosh },
        { "erf", erf },
        { "erfc", erfc },
        { "floor", floor },
        { "gamma", tgamma },
        { "ln", log },
        { "log", log10 },
        { "round", round },
        { "sin", sin },
        { "sinh", sinh },
        { "sqrt", sqrt },
        { "tan", tan },
        { "tanh", tanh },
        { "trunc", trunc }
    };
    struct math_fun *match = bsearch(str, /* count */
                                     functions,   /* array */
                                     sizeof functions / sizeof *functions, /* array len */
                                     sizeof *functions,            /* element size */
                                     compare_function_name); /* comparator */
    if (!match) { return 0; }

    /* modify argument to point after the function name */
    *str += strlen(match->name);
    return match->func;
}


int main(void)
{
    const char *input_tan = "tan";
    const char *input_tanh = "tanh";
    return func(&input_tan) != tan || *input_tan
        || func(&input_tanh) != tanh || *input_tanh;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A novel and interesting piece of code.

A refreshing application.

**Why `static`?**

`static double (*func(const char **const str))(double)` looks like it deserves to be public (non-`static`) function, albeit with a less common name.

**UB with negative characters**

`isalpha(sa[l])` risks UB when `sa[l] < 0`.  The usual solution is to use an `unsigned char *` to the string.  The C `str...()` library functions internally perform with characters as *unsigned* even when `char` is *signed*.

```
// const char *const sa = *(const char *const *)a
const unsigned char *const sa = *(const unsigned char *const *)a
```

**`(const)` not needed in cast**

```
//const char *const sa = *(const char *const *)a
const char *const sa = *(const char **)a
```

**Questionable `restrict`**

`static int c(const void *const restrict a, const void *const restrict b) {` does not benefit with `restrict`.  Function still performs as well without it as it is OK for strings to overlap here.

`bsearch()` expects a `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)`**

I'd recommend `c()` use the same.

```
// static int c(const void *const restrict a, const void *const restrict b)
static int c(const void *a, const void *b)
```

On further review - use of `restrict` is dubious here as `bsearch()` is not specified to not call the compare function with pointers to the same memory.

**Incorrect subtraction**

This make little difference as `s[]` uses characters all with positive values, yet in general, `sa[l]-sb[l]` should be done with `unsigned char*` pointers.  That is what `strcmp()` does.

**Integer function name?**

Strange to find `"abs"`, an integer function name, and not `"fabs"`.

**Type Bug**

`strlen(r)` expects a `char *`, but is getting a `char **`.  Maybe it should be `strlen(*r)`?

To me, this also implies insufficient testing.

**Wide lines**

Consider a narrower presentation.

**Other math.h functions**

```
double exp2(double x);   // Hard to use given OP's rules
double expm1(double x);
double log10(double x);  // OP uses non-standard name log
double log2(double x);   // Hard to use given OP's rules
double logb(double x); 
double lgamma(double x);
double tgamma(double x);
double nearbyint(double x);
double rint(double x);
```

**Useful custom functions**

```
double nextafter_up(double x);
double nextafter_down(double x);
```

**`const` objects**

Not a fan of `const` objects parameters in such short code.  It takes away clarity and adds little.

**Why the extra level of indirection?**

Why

```
static double (*func(const char **const str))(double) {
```

and not

```
static double (*func(const char *const str))(double) {
  ...
  const char *const *const r = bsearch(&str, s, ...
```

?

**Alternative**

Consider looking for a `'('`

```
const char *s = "log(100)";
```

Code could then extend to `"hypot(3,4)", etc.

**Unneeded ()**

`sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s)` could be `sizeof s / sizeof *s`.  As with such style issues, code to your group's standard.

Comment: Thanks for the review. To respond to some of the items: **Integer function name** The code only deals with doubles, so calling the function `fabs` within the strings that the code processes is redundant. **Type Bug** I later discovered this issue upon further testing but forgot to update the question. **Why the extra level of indirection?** So that the pointer passed can be updated to point to the character after the found function name, similar to the `endptr` argument of `strtol`, `strtod`, etc. **Consider looking for a `'('`** That is the plan for the app in which this function is used.

Comment: As for the usage of `restrict`, it is to my experience that since parameters in C are pass by value, defining them as `const` or `restrict` within the function does not have to match as in the function declaration. Also I read in manual pages that the first argument of `compar` shall be a pointer to the key, and the second shall be a pointer to an element in the array being searched. So as long as I do not pass a pointer to an element in the array as the key to `bsearch`, there should be no problem with `restrict`.

Comment: @user16217248 My concern related to using `compar()` with `qsort()`.  Answer amended.