# Command line calculator in C

Tags: c, parsing, calculator, math-expression-eval, portability

This code is an arithmetic parser as is the code in a [previous question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283598/264812). However this parser handles floating point arguments and mathematical functions, and handles them without needing to define a new function for every precedence level. The component to parse function names is the topic of a [different previous question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/281661/264812).

The code uses a recursive approach to parse strings of mathematical expressions. `u` is short for *unary*, which handles individual terms, such as individual numbers, functions, or parenthesized expressions. `b` is short for *binary*, which handles the binary operators. Associativity and precedence is respected. The first term is evaluated. Then, any operators operating on it are checked. If they are found, the right operand of the operator is recursively evaluated by passing the precedence operator to the function. The function only evaluates until an operator of precedence lower or equal (for right-to-left associativity) or lower (for left-to-right associativity) precedence is encountered. As such, the recursion ends, and the previous recursion level handles the rest. The workings are complicated but I am trying my best to explain them.

As always, if my code is needlessly non-portable, or could use general improvement advice, corrections or comments would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
static size_t l;
static int c(const void *const restrict a, const void *const restrict b) {
    const unsigned char *const sa = *(const unsigned char *const *)a, *const sb = *(const unsigned char *const *)b;
    const int cmp = memcmp(sa, sb, l = strlen((const char *)sb));
    return cmp ? cmp : isalpha(sa[l]) ? sa[l]-sb[l] : 0;
}
static double (*func(const char **const str))(double) {
    static const char *const s[] = {"abs", "acos", "acosh", "asin", "asinh", "atan", "atanh", "cbrt", "ceil", "cos", "cosh", "erf", "erfc", "exp", "expb", "floor", "gamma", "lgamma", "lb", "ln", "log", "round", "sin", "sinh", "sqrt", "tan", "tanh", "trunc"};
    static double (*const f[])(double) = {fabs, acos, acosh, asin, asinh, atan, atanh, cbrt, ceil, cos, cosh, erf, erfc, exp, exp2, floor, tgamma, lgamma, log2, log, log10, round, sin, sinh, sqrt, tan, tanh, trunc};
    const char *const *const r = bsearch(str, s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s), sizeof(*s), c);
    if (r) {
        *str += l;
        return f[r-s];
    }
    return NULL;
}
static double u(const char **);
static double b(const char **const str, const unsigned l) {
    *str += l != 0; // `l` will only be nonzero if recursively called by `b`, in which case there is an operator character to skip over
    for (double r = u(str);;) {
        while (isspace(**str))
            ++*str;
        switch (**str) {
            case '^':
                if (l <= 3) // Using `<=` instead of `<` gives `^` right-to-left associativity
                    r = pow(r, b(str, 3));
                else
                    break;
                continue;
            case '*':
                if (l < 2)
                    r *= b(str, 2);
                else
                    break;
                continue;
            case '/':
                if (l < 2)
                    r /= b(str, 2);
                else
                    break;
                continue;
            case '%':
                if (l < 2)
                    r = fmod(r, b(str, 2));
                else
                    break;
                continue;
            case '+':
                if (l < 1)
                    r += b(str, 1);
                else
                    break;
                continue;
            case '-':
                if (l < 1)
                    r -= b(str, 1);
                else
                    break;
                continue;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
static double u(const char **const str) {
    while (isspace(**str))
        ++*str;
    if (isdigit(**str) || **str == '.')
        return strtod(*str, (char **)str);
    if (isalpha(**str)) {
        double (*f)(double) = func(str);
        if (f)
            return f(u(str));
    } else switch (*(*str)++) {
        case '+':
            return +u(str);
        case '-':
            return -u(str);
        case '(': {
            register const double r = b(str, 0);
            if (*(*str)++ == ')')
                return r;
        }
    }
    return NAN;
}
#include <errno.h>
int main(const int argc, const char *const *argv) {
    while (*++argv)
        if (printf("%g\n", b(&(const char *){*argv}, 0)) < 0)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that u /  b is short for unary / binary; that is invaluable documentation for the current code. But it should be superfluous. Just declare static double `unary` and be done with it. In a related vein, sometimes `l` denotes `length` and sometimes a precedence `level`. Add two or so characters to at least one of those identifiers already. Consider stack allocating it rather than using static, so it goes out of scope. Don't compilers mostly ignore "register" advice these days? It's too bad we don't have a bunch of pairs that look like `("abs", fabs), ...`

Comment: `return strtod(*str, (char **)str);`  fails to detect no conversion

Comment: ```int main(const int argc, const char *const *argv) {
    while (*++argv)``` ====> I suggest looking at your last review.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The only side effect of that is `.` is parsed as `0`. `c()` is used as the comparison function for `bsearch()`.

Comment: `if (l <= 3) // Using <= instead of < gives ^ right-to-left associativity` is unclear.  I'd expect `if (l < 4)` to give left to right associativity. `if (l < 4)` and `if (l <= 3)` are the same thing.  Are you certain you have right to left associativity with `if (l <= 3)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes. If I require the next operator to have greater precedence before entering a recursion, all operators of same precedence will be evaluated iteratively by the loop of the caller. If I only require that it is greater or equal in precedence, then each new operator encountered will enter a new recursion, causing them to be grouped as `2^(2^(2^2))`. If this seems far fetched, I have tested it and it works, for what it is worth.

Comment: You have linked previous reviews, but don't seem to have learnt from them.  Why should anyone volunteer to review your code if you ignore most suggestions?

Comment: ...more specifically, your code invokes undefined behaviour (would likely result in a segmentation violation signal) because you didn't check if `argv` was valid before dereferencing it. It could easily be rendered `NULL`. And what do you suppose the `register` keyword does?

Comment: @Haris `register` means that the variable will have a short lifetime and/or will be used often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Avoid global variables for this task**

The key problem, in this case, is the added difficultly in proving code correctness.

Alternative:

In `func()`, instead of `*str += l;`, use `*str += strlen(r);`

Note: use of `l` as a global and `l` as a local variable  decreases code clarity.

I'd re-write it further:

```
#define SL(s) (s), sizeof (s) - 1
struct {
  const char *name;
  unsigned len;
  double (*const func)(double);
} pairs[] = {
  { SL("abs"), abs},
  { SL("acosh"), acosh},
  ... 
};
#undef SL
... and then `bsearch()` on `pairs` and avoid all `strlen()` calls.
```

**Formatting**

First, use an auto-formatter.

Target your audience.  On this site, the width of your code is about 310% the width of the window.  Adjust your auto formatting to stay within 120%, or even 100%.

**Plan for the future**

Move the parsing code to another file, say `dparse.c`.  Form `dparse.h` and `main.c`.

That way your good work can now readily get used on larger applications.

**Detect no conversion**

Do not assume a convertible string must begin with a digit/`'.'`.  Other possibilities include `,` (other locale), `i`, `I`, `n`, `N`, ....
`strtod()` also has "In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms may be accepted."

[The only side effect of that is . is parsed as 0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283641/command-line-calculator-in-c/283658?noredirect=1#comment562854_283641) is not wholly correct.

Better to let `strtod()` determine what is convertible.

```
    // if (isdigit(**str) || **str == '.')
    //   return strtod(*str, (char **)str);
    char *endptr;
    double val = strtod(*str, &endptr);
    if (*str == endptr) {
      // Handle no conversion
    } else {
      *str = endptr;
      return val;
    }
```

Code then likely needs to test for `+`, `-` first.

Comment: *'In `func()`, instead of `*str += l;`, use `*str += strlen(r);`.'* I would rather not recalculate the `strlen` unnecessarily. A quick and dirty fix was to use a global variable. A new solution was to manually add the length to the string pointer from within the `c` function upon returning 0. *'Better to let `strtod()` determine what is convertible.'* The `digit()` and `== '.'` was another quick and dirty fix. Thanks for the alternative suggestion that I had not yet thought of.

Comment: But your new solution that avoids all `strlen` calls might be even better.

Comment: But either way, I agree that the global `l` should go. Like you said, it makes proving correctness harder, and also, when it comes to planning for the future, if I make this a function for use in other programs instead of a command line tool, the use of the global `l` is thread-unsafe.

Comment: I dislike the macro that expands `s` twice.  But it's used in a very small scope, and with an `#undef` immediately following, I would grudgingly pass that.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fair enough.  Alterative suggestion?

Comment: @TobySpeight Why? This way the string lengths are not magic numbers.

Comment: @user16217248, Macros that expand their arguments more than once are a serious bug risk, because when arguments with side-effects get substituted, those side-effects are repeated despite appearing just once in the unexpanded source (standard example: `MACRO(++i)`).  That's why I dislike them, and strive to avoid them whenever possible.  In this particular case, the benefit is probably worthwhile, but adding `#undef SL` as soon as reasonably possible would be a help to reviewers and future maintainers, as that keeps the danger clearly isolated.

Comment: @TobySpeight It would only be used with constant strings. Using such a macro with any expression with side effects would cause a non-constant initializer error.

Comment: Indeed, but the reviewer's nose always twitches when they see a common danger sign.  And leaving it defined after we've finished with it means holding that knowledge for longer - my recommendation, I'll repeat again, is to `#undef` as soon as is reasonable.

Comment: @TobySpeight Had I taken more time, It think a macro (better named too) to initialize all members would be cleanest: `#define PAIRS_INIT(s, f) (s), sizeof (s) - 1, (f) ... { PAIRS_INIT("abs", abs)}, ... #undef PAIRS_INIT`.

Answer (score 7):

## General Observations

I'm going to address coding style here, since the code is almost unreadable.

If you are interested in getting your code reviewed you may want to pay attention to what the reviewers say. In an earlier review @chux-ReinstateMonica wrote this:

> Non-standard main() signature
>
> Drop the const.
>
> Some compilers may whine. Note: "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program," C17dr § 5.1.2.2.1 2.

There is really no point in reviewing your code if you aren't going to use our suggestions.

## Readability

The code is very hard to follow.

### Vertical Spacing

The code needs vertical white space to improve readability. Generally logic blocks should be separated by blank lines, functions should definitely be separated by blank lines.

This was mentioned by @chux-ReinstateMonica in a previous review.

### Line Length

Limit the length of any lines so that the reader does not lose track of the line they are on. Old screens were limited to 80 characters of width, it isn't necessary to stick to 80 characters, but it would be best to keep it under 100 characters. Having to do horizontal scrolling while reading code is bad.

### Variable and Function Names

The use of single character or 2 character variable names reduces the readability of the code. If `u` stands for `unary` use `unary` because it is clearer and doesn't need a paragraph to explain it.

```
static size_t l;
```

The variable l above is global to the file, a single character global variable is definitely a bad practice because finding it will be very difficult.

### Late Include File

Why isn't the include for `errno.h` up with the other include files at the top of the file? Why is `errno.h` included at all since it doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: And of course, `l` is one of the worst variable names to use at any time, due to its visual similarity with `1`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Absolutely!

Comment: @TobySpeight No `l` object names is a good idea, especially around [Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel) ;-).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica shouldn't that be Noe l?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50978463/16217248

Comment: @user16217248 Agreed, given "if my code is needlessly non-portable" for this code, best to use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, right from the C spec.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But according to that answer, `const` qualifier for top level arguments, such as `int` or pointers *themselves* (excluding their pointed-to type) can also be used as it does not affect the prototype of the function at all.

Comment: @user16217248 `int main(const int argc, const char *const *argv)` is certainly not compatible with `int main(const int argc, char **argv)`. Answer refers to `const` as in the arguments like `int main(const int argc, char ** const argv)` as maybe OK. Unless you have compelling stated reasons, best code as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. "as it does not affect the prototype of the function at all" is not supported by the C spec. `main()`, among C functions is special.  Avoid attempting to _improve_ it. If still in doubt, research stack overflow answers/post a question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But wouldn't `int main(const int argc, char **const argv)` be compatible with `int main(int argc, char **argv)`? According to the SO answer, it would be.

Comment: @user16217248 That SO answer is not authoritative.  Again, `main()` is special and has special requirements.  Why do you want to use `int main(const int argc, char **const argv)` vs. the incredible common and well understood `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As general practice, I like to write variables (including function parameters) that never change as `const`.

Comment: Code's use of `const` is overdone here in function _definitions_ and reduces clarity, especially on short functions. It is never needed in function _declarations_. On long functions, it has some merit, yet it use falls into a _style_ issue. Style issues are best coded against group's coding standard - so I tend to avoid those holy wars.  I suspect if you coded all this with and without `const` parameters and inquired what most folks like, they would choose without.  IAC, best to leave `main()` alone - it is special (read C spec 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup) & no need to be any different here.

Comment: @user16217248 Should you desire to post another iteration, take your time (at least a week, maybe month) and reflect on all the feedback in this and previous posts/answers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fair.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to delete `#include <errno.h>` after finding out that I do not need `errno` in my program.

Answer (score 7):

***Don't write clever code:***

```
if (printf("%g\n", b(&(const char *){*argv}, 0)) < 0)
```

You know you’re brilliant, but maybe you’d like to understand what you did 2 weeks from now.

Similarly, this expression `return cmp ? cmp : isalpha(sa[l]) ? sa[l]-sb[l] : 0;` seems to say:
*Read my code, and tremble.*

Yes, you should write concise code, but not to the point where it hurts readability. I'd rather opt for an `if/else` here.

***Don’t put multiple statements on a single line unless you have something to hide:***

```
const unsigned char *const sa = *(const unsigned char *const *)a, *const sb = *(const unsigned char *const *)b;
```

Multiple assignments, either. The above snippet is better as:

```
const unsigned char *const sa = *(const unsigned char *const *)a;
const unsigned char *const sb = *(const unsigned char *const *)b;
```

***Use descriptive function/variable names:***

> "u is short for unary, which handles individual terms, such as
> individual numbers, functions, or parenthesized expressions. b is
> short for binary."

Names must be recognizable and quickly distinguishable. The above comment wouldn't be required if the functions used self-descriptive names. `parse_unary()` is self-descriptive, `u()` is not. `parse_binary()` is self-descriptive, `b()` is not.

*Aside*: The follow-up failed to show any significant improvements. I do not see any, or most of, the changes @chux suggested in this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283624/265278). People would be more likely to review your code if you'd take their suggestions into consideration.

And I appreciate you for using `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: The 'clever' code seems the most straightforward way to me to write *If printf fails, exit with failure status*. Maybe I should have added a comment explaining this line.

Comment: As an observer, I agree that `if (printf(…) < 0)` is natural.  ___However___, embedding the call to `b()` within the `printf()` is too dense for my taste (especially with that cast which wouldn't be necessary if you used a standard signature for `main()`).

Comment: @TobySpeight It's not a cast, it's a compound literal, to create an anonymous copy in case modifying the values of `argv` is problematic for whatever reason.

Comment: *"Complexity is more apparent to readers than writers. If you write a piece of code and it seems simple to you, but other people think it is complex, then it is complex.

“Obvious” is in the mind of the reader: it’s easier to notice that someone else’s code is nonobvious than to see problems with your own code. If someone reading your code says it’s not obvious, then it’s not obvious, no matter how clear it may seem to you."*
— A Philosophy of Software Design, John Ousterhout